# Getting oracle JDBC jar from from Nexus with gradle

Tags: gradle, nexus

I seen this question but nothing seemed to help. I will do my best to make the answer better and hopefully show a solution.

In my `build.gradle` under `dependencies` I have:

`compile files('oracle/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar')` where I was manually placing the jar in the directory.

What I am doing now is trying to pull it from nuxus.

I my local `gradle.properties` I added my username and password but it pulls ALL dependencies and is not able to get them all from nexus and fails. I want to just pull one `jar` (jbdc) with gradle build.

Error is here:

```
> Configure project :api 
init.gradle/NexusRepositoryPlugin:    MavenRepo at https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ removed.
init.gradle/NexusRepositoryPlugin:    __plugin_repository__Gradle Central Plugin Repository kept (not a Maven repository).
init.gradle/NexusRepositoryPlugin:    MavenRepo at https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ removed.
init.gradle/NexusRepositoryPlugin:    BintrayJCenter at https://jcenter.bintray.com/ removed.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':api:detachedConfiguration1'.
> Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.1.RELEASE.
  Required by:
      project :api
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.1.RELEASE.
```

Advice?

Comment: Which repositories are you using? Only a private one? Only a public one? A combination? Obviously your project requires spring boot. Why do you expect Gradle to only try to fetch the JDBC jar? This question is missing information around the project setup to enable a proper answer.

Comment: @LouisJacomet it is a private nexus repo and it doesn't have all the dependencies. I just need the `jdbc` and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the question indicates that you are *replacing* the public repository declaration with a private one that contains only that JDBC jar.

You should instead leave the public repository declaration and *add* the private one. Gradle will then search for the JDBC jar in both the first time and retrieve it.